# one to one jpa mapping DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have 2 tables, Person and phone and they have a one to one relationship.

```
**Person**
person_id
name

**Phone**
phone_id
person_id -- foreign key and not null constraint
number
```

This is how I have mapped it:

```
Person{
        @Column(name="person_id")
        Long personId;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
                    fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
          private Phone phone;

      public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
        phone.setPerson(this);
    }
}

Phone{
        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
        private Person person;
}
```

I am using spring data. So when I try to save a Person like so, it gives me `DataIntegrityViolationException - HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint table: "PHONE" column: "person_id"`

```
Person person = new Person();
Phone phone = new Phone();
//populate phone and person properties.
person.setPhone(phone);
repository.save(person);
repository.flush();
```

When I remove the not null constraint from the table and execute the same insert, then it passess successfully.

Comment: Is your field named person_id or phone_id? Your error and supplied code don’t match, so either there’s another field, or you supplied code is wrong.

Comment: Didn't want to copy paste the code, so mistyped it. Updated it above

Comment: Added to the answer I gave.  Did any of that fix it for you?

Answer (score 1):

You never supplied a value for person_id from your entity. My guess is that you meant to use person_id on your person field from Phone, but mistyped as phone_id.

In this case, the null constraint error is appropriate.

Edited: Alternatively, your ID field on Person is missing both the @Id and @GeneratedValue annotations which could also explain the null constraint violation.

Comment: thank you, I had mistyped it. I didn't want to copy paste the real code here so I had to type it. Updated it. The problem still persists.

Comment: One more confirmation then: is Person::personId annotated @GeneratedValue @Id?  It’s not included and could also cause the problem shown, as the value of personId is never initialized, hence null and in violation of the constraint as shown above.